# Angular suppress popup on load when arrived from Email

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm facing an issue, I have an angular 14 application which when loads displays the modal popup with route `http://localhost:4200/select-role`

app.routing.module.ts

```
{ path:'select-role', component: SwitchRoleDialogComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

Its just an popup with list of roles and radio buttons so user selects one click proceed and lands on landing page with route `http://localhost:4200/home`. I call this popup in my `AppComponent`.

Now, I've a scenario where from the email link when I click, I need to go to some particular route and suppress this popup.

email link - `http://localhost:4200/wf/review/152`,
hence, to handle email route path this I've created an `LoadingIncomingAppComponent`

```
{ path: 'wf/review/:id', component: LoadingIncomingAppComponent},
```

LoadingIncomingAppComponent

```
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.id= +params.get('id');
      if (this.id) {
        this.someSvc.currentId= this.id;
        this.router.navigate(['/review']) //navigate to my destination;
      }
    })
```

With this changes i land to the destination but with overlay, how can i suppress `SwitchRoleDialogComponent` popup triggered from AppComponent when I navigate from email else it should display as it does?

Answer (score 1):

When you load `LoadingIncomingAppComponent` on the `ngOnInit()` emit an event using `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` on a common service, then subscribe to that subject emissions on the app component and close that popup manually, if its possible to close it directly use that!

You can also flag certian routes into an array like `this.ignoreTheseRoutes = ['wf/review']` and prevent the popup being open when the route belongs to these routes like so

```
// below line check if the router url matches any 
// of the flagged routes where the popup need not open!
if(!this.ignoreTheseRoutes.some((path: string) => this.router.url.includes(path))) { 
    // open the popup!
}
```